# How to access a variable from python inside Jain data js script?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to access certian variables from my python code above of json data. I am new to using python and json together so im not sure how to go about this. here is my code:

```
 global proxy_addressed
        ordered_proxies = []
        for numb in range(0, num_tasks):
            if numb % num_proxies == 0:
                random.shuffle(add_proxy)
            proxy_addressed = add_proxy[numb % num_proxies]

            ordered_proxies.append(proxy_addressed)

            global pvar
            for lines in ordered_proxies:
                pvar = lines.split(':')  # rotating proxy or host

            PROXY_HOST = pvar[0]
            PROXY_PORT = pvar[1]
            PROXY_USER = pvar[2]
            PROXY_PASS = pvar[3]
            print(PROXY_HOST)
            manifest_json = """
            {
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "manifest_version": 2,
                "name": "Chrome Proxy",
                "permissions": [
                    "proxy",
                    "tabs",
                    "unlimitedStorage",
                    "storage",
                    "<all_urls>",
                    "webRequest",
                    "webRequestBlocking"
                ],
                "background": {
                    "scripts": ["background.js"]
                },
                "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
            }
            """

            background_js = """
            var config = {
                    mode: "fixed_servers",
                    rules: {
                      singleProxy: {
                        scheme: "http","""
            """         host: "{}",
                        port: "{}""""".format(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT)
            """
                      },
                      bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
                    }
                  };
            """

            """
            chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

            function callbackFn(details) {
                return {
                    authCredentials: {"""
            """         username: "{}",
                        password: "{}""""".format(PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)
            """
                    }
                };
            }
            chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

            function callbackFn(details) {
                return {
                    authCredentials: {
                        username: PROXY_USER,
                        password: PROXY_PASS
                    }
                };
            }

            chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                        callbackFn,
                        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                        ['blocking']
            );
            """

            pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

            with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
                zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
                zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)

            co = Options()
            co.add_argument("--start-maximized")
            co.add_extension(pluginfile)
            co.add_argument(win_size)
            driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver", chrome_options=co)
            driver.execute_script("window.open('{}')".format(page_address))
```

I am trying to use the variables PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER and PROXY_PASS inside of the manifest/background_json and it is unsuccessful. How can i call variables from the code into the json?

EDIT: I should be a bit more specific, i need to input the code into the js script that i wrote that then is being used by a json data. So really its like i need to be able to access a python variable in a js script.

EDIT 2: I now get an error in the console which i didnt get before:

```
[22456:27868:0111/201424.041:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(935)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
```

EDIT 3: The error above was because i accidentally put PROXY_PASS instead of PROXY_PORT into the function that needed the port.

Comment: if you have string then use string formating - ie `"username: {}".format(PROXY_USER)` or `f-string` - ie.`f"username: {PROXY_USER}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have string then use string formatting

```
"""username: "{}",
   password: "{}" """.format(PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)
```

or `f-string`

```
f"""username: "{PROXY_USER}",
    password: "{PROXY_PASS}" """
```

---

If you have other `{` `}` in string then you will have to use `{{` and `}}`

```
PROXY_USER = "Hello"
PROXY_PASS = "World"

result = """{{
   username: "{}",
   password: "{}"
}}""".format(PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)

print(result)
```

or

```
PROXY_USER = "Hello"
PROXY_PASS = "World"

result = f"""{{
    username: "{PROXY_USER}",
    password: "{PROXY_PASS}"
}}"""

print(result)
```

Result

```
{
   username: "Hello",
   password: "World"
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help, is there any way you can show this incorporated into the code? Ive never used js before so i dont really know what im doing and although this seems right im getting errors in my program.

Comment: for Python it is only normal string, not JavaScript code - so use string formatting for this. I used part of your string in example so you have example with your code.

Comment: eventually you can use string concatenation: `'{ username: "' + PROXY_USER + '", password: "' + PROXY_PASS + '" }'` and then you don't have to change `{` and `}`

Comment: i was using string formatting and its uses my ip not the ip i want it to use. Could this be because the port is an int and not a string?

Comment: maybe this proxy server sends your IP - not all proxy servers hide your IP.

Comment: well when i use the proxy information hard coded into those fields it works and uses the ip of the proxy but when i use the variables it doesnt work and it uses my ip as a backup almost. Do you think i could send u a proxy and you can see if it works for you?

Comment: BTW: you can always use `print()` to see if you created correct string.

Comment: BTW: did you used this with Selenium ? Maybe problem is not code but Selenium which may not uses some standard setttings - as I know Selenium as default doesn't use default profile but it create new empty profile.

Comment: i did use selenium, the point of using this example is that i have to create a new user profile and use that with these instructions to add a proxy to it. Without this profile that i created the code itself doesnt work.

Comment: i edited my code above, it still doesn't work but i feel i'm getting closer as i am probably still doing something wrong... Do you think you can look at it again?

Comment: i also now get an error in the console which i didnt get before. it is included in the edit above.